# Would like help with translations of the seals on a floral artwork

Tags: translation, seal

[image]

There are three seals on the bottom right corner.

Comment: top one: "翰墨" its literal meaning is "pen&ink", it is just a way to say "arts of calligraphy and paintng" ; bottom large one: "杨德安（or文?）" it's the artist's name, the other one is too small to tell